# Swing component for entering a sequence of pairs

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a Java application, and I need an user-friendly component for entering a lot of pairs easily, I think the most friendly way to do it is make a table, somewhat like a spreadsheet and let them edit that manually, but i'm not sure what listeners to use for that, and it seems rather complicated, what I want to know is if there is a nicer component for that task.

Comment: You've tried `JTable` and it doesn't meet your needs? It seems like exactly the component you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a JTable.  You can write a class which extends [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) to handle display, validation, etc.  It handles most of the work for you.  You just need to override the few methods you care about.  The [Java tutorial on Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) has a pretty good overview, but pretty much all you need to do to make your cells editable is have isCellEditable() return true and implement an appropriate setValueAt() function.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'll do, I didn't know about the "isCellEditable"